# How do I display video once the item is clicked on playlist? Any idea

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, android-logcat

======================MainPlay=================================================
====This is the first where all the files are displayed and can select file to play======

```
package com.example.droid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class mainplay extends ListActivity {


          private ArrayList<Video> videoList;
          private ListView videoView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.videoplaylist);

            videoView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);  
            videoList = new ArrayList<Video>();
            getVideoList();


            Collections.sort(videoList, new Comparator<Video>(){
                  public int compare(Video a, Video b){
                    return a.getTTL().compareTo(b.getTTL());
                  }
                }); 

            VideoAdapter VAdp = new VideoAdapter(this, videoList);
            videoView.setAdapter(VAdp);

        }




        public void getVideoList(){
            //retrieve video info   
            ContentResolver videoResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri videoUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor videoCursor = videoResolver.query(videoUri, null, null, null, null);

            if(videoCursor!=null && videoCursor.moveToFirst()){
                  //get columns
                  int titleColumn = videoCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
                  int idColumn = videoCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);

                  //add videos to list
                  do {
                    long thisId = videoCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                    String thisTitle = videoCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    Log.e("video", thisTitle);
                    videoList.add(new Video(thisId, thisTitle));
                  }
                  while (videoCursor.moveToNext());


                  ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                  OnItemClickListener itemClick = new OnItemClickListener(){

                      @Override
                      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                              int position, long id) {

                          Intent Droid=new Intent(mainplay.this,DroidActivity.class);
                          startActivity(Droid);


                      }

                  };
                  listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClick);
            }

        }

}
```

==================SECOND SCREEN=======================
 ======This the screen where the video should play once the item is selected on mainplay=====

```
package com.example.droid;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class DroidActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_droid);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DroidActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait. . .");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        pDialog.show();


        VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVid);
        Uri vid = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.vdroid);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vid);

        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        vidView.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.droid, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its only one example of Solution.
send bundle with the Video ID (i am Assuming that Column Id is unique)
Example :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("VIDEO_ID",video_id);
Intent Droid=new Intent(mainplay.this,DroidActivity.class);
Droid.putExtra(bundle);                          
startActivity(Droid);
```

this will send the choice to the other Activity

on the DriodActivity

on the onStart/OnResume
use this

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("VIDEO ID")
```

now load the Video from the list by the columid you sent.
by moving over the list and when columnId is equal to the selected video id ..